# fatal error: Index out of range when refreshing Collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, fatal-error, pull-to-refresh, indexoutofrangeexception

I added a pull to refresh to UICollectionView but I get the same error even though I've tried many things.

UICollectionView works fine.pull to refresh also works fine but I get this error if I pull repeatedly.

**Fatal error: Index out of range**

the function should not work again before it is completely finished?

how can I solve this problem?

```swift
    func veriCek(){

        var tempOrdersList = [HomeFeedVideo]()

        self.posts.removeAll()
        tempOrdersList.removeAll()

        Alamofire.request("**************************", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                //print(response.data!)
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let json = result as! NSDictionary
                    //print(json)

                    let dataArray = json["sonuclar"] as! NSArray;

                    print("Data items count: \(dataArray.count)")
                    for item in dataArray { // loop through data items

                       // ... some code

                        let post = HomeFeedVideo(artistName: artistName, commentlikes: commentlikes, likeStatus: likeStatus, name: name, profilePics: profilePics, time: time, userID: userID, username: username, videoContent: videoContent, videoID: videoID, videoLikes: videoLikes, videoName: videoName, videoPath: videoPath, view: view, status: groupStatus, groupResponse: groupRes, thumbnail: thumbnail)
                        tempOrdersList.append(post)

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.posts = tempOrdersList
                        self.user = User(dictionary: json as! [String : Any])
                        self.navigationItem.title = self.user?.username
                        self.playerCollect?.reloadData()
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Please post all error message.

Comment: @mussaCharles all error message = Fatal error: Index out of range
2019-09-16 05:50:02.554997+0300 appname [52904:858042] Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Check my answer, if it does not fix please share your dataSource method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting the error in collectionView datasource method
cellForItemAt(indexPath:) method. You might be attempting to set a cell post while your data is removed. If you share your dataSource implementation, I might be able to find the issue. Try to set post only if your data is not empty.

In cellForItemAt method add this check: -

```
if !posts.isEmpty {
// TODO: - Set your cell's post
}
```

Comment: Glad that I could help,  Happy coding :)